# Accessing bit-field in C by its address

Tags: c, pointers, bit-fields

What is the reason behind not allowing to access a bit field in C using its address, is it cause it might not be an address that is not system word aligned ..? or as it doesn't make sense to get bit's address within a byte...?(cause this types pointer arithmetic will be awkward ?)

Comment: What value would you expect the "address of a bit" to have??

Comment: You can modify bits by requesting the char it is in, and then use bitmasking operations.

Answer (score 7):

Bits do not have addresses. That's why you can't refer to them by address. The granularity of addressing is the `char`.

I guess the reasoning is that the language was design to match the architecture it targeted, and I know of no machine which allows addressing of individual bits.

Answer (score 4):

The smallest unit of addressable memory in C is a `char`, because this corresponds to the smallest unit of addressable memory on most CPU architectures.<sup>*</sup>  It doesn't make sense to talk about the address of a bit.

---

<sub>* One could imagine a hypothetical machine that allowed addressing of individual bits, but it would be pretty esoteric.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In c smallest addressable unit of memory is considered a Byte. A pointer points to a memory location which can be of any data_type (a pointer is also another variable). Bits receding in byte don't have any address , rather they do have a bit position.

So basically you can not point to particular bit , you can point to a byte or whole word.